# Find duplicate Object value and replace with new custom value dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My array like this:

```js
var array = [
      { dates: "2020-12-25", class: "first" },
      { dates: "2020-12-26", class: "last" },
      { dates: "2021-06-11", class: "first" },      
      { dates: "2021-06-18", class: "last" },
      { dates: "2021-06-18", class: "first" },     
      { dates: "2021-05-15", class: "booked" },
      { dates: "2021-05-16", class: "booked" },
      { dates: "2021-05-17", class: "booked" },
      { dates: "2021-05-18", class: "booked" },
      { dates: "2021-05-19", class: "last" },
      { dates: "2021-05-19", class: "first" },      
];

for(u=0; u <array.length;u++){
    var valueArr = array.map(function(item){ return item.dates });
    var isDuplicate = valueArr.some(function(item, idx){ 
        return valueArr.indexOf(item) != idx 
    });
    if (valueArr){
        array[u] = {
            class: 'first-last'
        };
    }
    array;
}
console.log(array);
```

I have duplicate object value in array like
`{date:2021-05-19,class:'first'},{date:2021-05-19,class:'last'}`
which have two different class **first** and **last**

I just want to find the duplicate value of the `{date:date:2021-05-19,}` key and update with class: `first-last`.

Comment: So you want to know how to do it... Tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, I tried many times but I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: SO community is expecting you to try something... And come over here with a specific blocking issue. Post what you tried and what is not working in the attempts to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to reduce the array, adding them to an object by their dates, and checking the accumulator if the date exists. If it does, change it's class else set the item.

Then we use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to return the result as an array

```js
var array = [{"dates":"2020-12-25","class":"first"},{"dates":"2020-12-26","class":"last"},{"dates":"2021-06-11","class":"first"},{"dates":"2021-06-18","class":"last"},{"dates":"2021-06-18","class":"first"},{"dates":"2021-05-15","class":"booked"},{"dates":"2021-05-16","class":"booked"},{"dates":"2021-05-17","class":"booked"},{"dates":"2021-05-18","class":"booked"},{"dates":"2021-05-19","class":"last"},{"dates":"2021-05-19","class":"first"}];

function findDup(data) {
  return Object.values(data.reduce(function(acc, item) {
    if (item.dates in acc) acc[item.dates]["class"] = "first-last";
    else acc[item.dates] = item;

    return acc;
  }, {}));
}

console.log(findDup(array));
```

Comment: Thank You so much. My issue has been fixed after using this code. Thank you once again.

Comment: Hi, mola, the above code is not working in internet explorer. It is showing a Syntax error. Is there any other way to write the same code that support on internet explorer too

Comment: @AlexJones I've edited the answer, changing the arrow functions to named functions, using `['class']` to change the class of the object.

Answer (score 0):

The following should also work for a more general case, where you might encounter more than two duplicates and only want the first and last class names of these items to appear in the `class` attribute:

```js
const arr = [{"dates":"2020-12-25","class":"first"},{"dates":"2020-12-26","class":"last"},{"dates":"2021-06-11","class":"first"},{"dates":"2021-06-18","class":"clast"},{"dates":"2021-06-18","class":"bfirst"},{"dates":"2021-05-15","class":"booked"},{"dates":"2021-05-16","class":"booked"},{"dates":"2021-05-19","class":"first"},{"dates":"2021-05-17","class":"booked"},{"dates":"2021-05-18","class":"booked"},{"dates":"2021-05-19","class":"second"},{"dates":"2021-05-19","class":"last"}]; 

const findDup = data =>{
const res=Object.values(data.reduce((acc, item) => {
 if (item.dates in acc) acc[item.dates].class[item.class] = 1
  else {
    let itm={...item};itm.class={[itm.class] :1};
    acc[item.dates] = itm   
  }
  return acc; }, {}))
res.forEach(d=>d.class=Object.keys(d.class).filter((_,i,a)=>!i||i==a.length-1).join("-"));
return res;
}

console.log(findDup(arr))
```

If you want to have *all class names* concatenated with `-` then simply *leave out* the part

```
.filter((_,i,a)=>!i||i==a.length-1)
```

that  in the current version - removes all "middle" elements from an array that are neither at the beginning nor at the end of the array.